# How to run a file in external storage in Python

Tags: python, flask

**At the beginning.**

I am Japanese. English may be inadequate. I look forward to working with you.

**What I want to achieve.**

I'm currently developing a web application and I'm using Flask. And I'm developing with Rasspberry pi.　 I want to execute the "message.py" file inside the USB connected as an external storage from the "app.py" file saved in Raspberry PI.

**File description.**

①「app.py」...Executable file stored on Raspberry Pi. If you enter characters in the text box displayed here and send, the value will be sent to "judg.py".

②「judg.py」...Find and execute the file to be executed from the external storage according to the value sent.

③「message.py」...This is one of the applications stored in external storage.

**Code**
「app.py」

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import judg

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', message="what shall I do?")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def form():
    field = request.form['field']
    if request.method == 'POST':
        res = judg.judg(field)
    return render_template('index.html', message=res['msg'], answer=res['ans'])

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='localhost')
```

「judg.py」

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '/media/pi/NAS')) 
import message

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def judg(field):
    if "message" in field:
        res = {'msg':"What shall I do?", 'ans':"message is Active!"}
        message.login()
        return res
    else:
        res = {'msg':"What shall I do?", 'ans':"Sorry.."}
        return res
```

「message.py」

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b'abc'

member_data = {}
message_data = []

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    global message_data
    if 'login' in session and session['login']:
        msg = 'Login id:' + session['id']
        return render_template('messages.html',
                               title='Messages',
                               message=msg,
                               data=message_data )
    else:
        return redirect('/login')
    
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def form():
    msg = request.form.get('comment')
    message_data.append((session['id'], msg))
    if len(message_data) > 25:
        message_data.pop(0)
    return redirect('/')

#login page access
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    return render_template('login.html',
                           title='Login',
                           err=False,
                           message='IDとパスワ−ドを入力:',
                           id='' )

#login
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_post():
    global member_data
    id = request.form.get('id')
    pswd = request.form.get('pass')
    if id in member_data:
        if pswd == member_data[id]:
            session['login'] = True
        else:
            session['login'] = False
    else:
        member_data[id] = pswd
        session['login'] = True
    session['id'] = id
    if session['login']:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render_template('login.html',
                               title='Login',
                               err=False,
                               message='パスワードが違います。',
                               id=id )

#logout
@app.route('/logout', methods=['GET'])
def logout():
    session.pop('id', None)
    session.pop('login')
    return redirect('/login')

if __name__== '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='localhost', port=5000)
```

**Directory structure**

「WebServer」 →(app.py), (judg.py), (「templates」→login.html, layout.html, index.html), (「static」→style.css)

「Skills」（External storage） →(message.py), (「templates」→layout.html, message.html), (「static」→style.css)

**What's happening now**

The behavior I expect is that typing "message" in the textbox will launch "message.py" and take you to the application login page.　I want to open it in another tab if possible. Currently, typing "message" does not cause an error, but instead of jumping to the login page, the message field on the original page says "message is active".

**Finally**

Since I am still a beginner in web applications, I would appreciate it if you could point out any mistakes.　If you're missing any information, let me know and I'll add it.　Thank you for browsing.